# Issue running a hql in local mode

Tags: hive

When i run the simple 1 record query, i beleive it is looking for the source path of the table in the local system which is not existing. I dont get this issue on cluster mode. Could you please help ?

Environment : 0.10 cdh3
set hive.exec.mode.local.auto=true

> hive (default)> select 'test' from dual;

Automatically selecting local only mode for query
Total MapReduce jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks is set to 0 since there's no reduce operator
Execution log at: /tmp/dm_hdp_dev_batch/dm_hdp_dev_batch_20130629230606_31b8a7bc-9618-4090-99ab-179f576ff5ae.log
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /tmp/dm_hdp_dev_batch/hive_2013-06-29_23-06-11_544_4259930697398507763/-mr-10000/1/emptyFile
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:562)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.CombineFileInputFormat$OneFileInfo.(CombineFileInputFormat.java:462)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.CombineFileInputFormat.getMoreSplits(CombineFileInputFormat.java:256)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.CombineFileInputFormat.getSplits(CombineFileInputFormat.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileInputFormatShim.getSplits(HadoopShimsSecure.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileInputFormatShim.getSplits(HadoopShimsSecure.java:358)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getSplits(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:387)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:983)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:975)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$500(JobClient.java:170)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:886)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:839)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1177)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:839)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:813)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:435)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver.main(ExecDriver.java:677)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:197)
Job Submission failed with exception 'java.io.FileNotFoundException(File does not exist: /tmp/dm_hdp_dev_batch/hive_2013-06-29_23-06-11_544_4259930697398507763/-mr-10000/1/emptyFile)'
Execution failed with exit status: 1
Obtaining error information

Task failed!
Task ID:
  Stage-1

Logs:

/tmp/dm_hdp_dev_batch/hive.log
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapRedTask

cat /tmp/dm_hdp_dev_batch/dm_hdp_dev_batch_20130629225252_b7170eb0-69a7-4b23-9c64-c84d4a292b86.log

```
2013-06-29 22:52:37,674 INFO  exec.ExecDriver (SessionState.java:printInfo(391)) - Execution log at: /tmp/dm_hdp_dev_batch/dm_hdp_dev_batch_20130629225252_b7170eb0-69a7-4b23-9c64-c84d4a292b86.log
2013-06-29 22:52:37,933 INFO  exec.ExecDriver (ExecDriver.java:execute(320)) - Using org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat
2013-06-29 22:52:37,939 INFO  exec.ExecDriver (ExecDriver.java:execute(342)) - adding libjars: file:///usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-builtins-0.9.0-cdh3u4b-SNAPSHOT.jar
2013-06-29 22:52:37,939 INFO  exec.ExecDriver (ExecDriver.java:addInputPaths(840)) - Processing alias dual
2013-06-29 22:52:37,940 INFO  exec.ExecDriver (ExecDriver.java:addInputPaths(858)) - **Adding input file hdfs://biggy.src.com/apps/mktg/m360/dev/data/Interim/intrm_Dummy
2013-06-29 22:52:37,940 INFO  exec.Utilities (Utilities.java:isEmptyPath(1807)) - Content **Summary not cached for hdfs://biggy.src.com/apps/mktg/m360/dev/data/Interim/intrm_Dummy
2013-06-29 22:52:38,121 INFO  exec.ExecDriver (ExecDriver.java:addInputPath(789)) - Changed input file to file:/tmp/dm_hdp_dev_batch/hive_2013-06-29_22-52-37_901_1833503522069219852/-mr-10000/1****
2013-06-29 22:52:38,131 INFO  util.NativeCodeLoader (NativeCodeLoader.java:<clinit>(43)) - Loaded the native-hadoop library
2013-06-29 22:52:38,291 INFO  jvm.JvmMetrics (JvmMetrics.java:init(71)) - Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
2013-06-29 22:52:38,292 INFO  exec.ExecDriver (ExecDriver.java:createTmpDirs(215)) - Making Temp Directory: hdfs://biggy.src.com/tmp/hive-dm_hdp_dev_batch/hive_2013-06-29_22-52-35_955_7873715221223972086/-ext-10001
2013-06-29 22:52:38,302 WARN  mapred.JobClient (JobClient.java:copyAndConfigureFiles(655)) - Use GenericOptionsParser for parsing the arguments. Applications should implement Tool for the same.
2013-06-29 22:52:38,379 WARN  snappy.LoadSnappy (LoadSnappy.java:<clinit>(36)) - Snappy native library is available
2013-06-29 22:52:38,380 INFO  snappy.LoadSnappy (LoadSnappy.java:<clinit>(44)) - Snappy native library loaded
2013-06-29 22:52:38,384 INFO  io.CombineHiveInputFormat (CombineHiveInputFormat.java:getSplits(370)) - CombineHiveInputSplit creating pool for file:/tmp/dm_hdp_dev_batch/hive_2013-06-29_22-52-37_901_1833503522069219852/-mr-10000/1; using filter path file:/tmp/dm_hdp_dev_batch/hive_2013-06-29_22-52-37_901_1833503522069219852/-mr-10000/1
2013-06-29 22:52:38,388 INFO  mapred.FileInputFormat (FileInputFormat.java:listStatus(196)) - Total input paths to process : 1
2013-06-29 22:52:38,390 INFO  mapred.JobClient (JobClient.java:run(925)) - Cleaning up the staging area file:/tmp/hadoop-dm_hdp_dev_batch/mapred/staging/dm_hdp_dev_batch1888887102/.staging/job_local_0001
2013-06-29 22:52:38,390 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation (UserGroupInformation.java:doAs(1180)) - PriviledgedActionException as:dm_hdp_dev_batch (auth:SIMPLE) cause:java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /tmp/dm_hdp_dev_batch/hive_2013-06-29_22-52-37_901_1833503522069219852/-mr-10000/1/emptyFile
2013-06-29 22:52:38,391 ERROR exec.ExecDriver (SessionState.java:printError(400)) - Job Submission failed with exception 'java.io.FileNotFoundException(File does not exist: /tmp/dm_hdp_dev_batch/hive_2013-06-29_22-52-37_901_1833503522069219852/-mr-10000/1/emptyFile)'
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /tmp/dm_hdp_dev_batch/hive_2013-06-29_22-52-37_901_1833503522069219852/-mr-10000/1/emptyFile
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:562)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.CombineFileInputFormat$OneFileInfo.<init>(CombineFileInputFormat.java:462)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.CombineFileInputFormat.getMoreSplits(CombineFileInputFormat.java:256)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.CombineFileInputFormat.getSplits(CombineFileInputFormat.java:212)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileInputFormatShim.getSplits(HadoopShimsSecure.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShimsSecure$CombineFileInputFormatShim.getSplits(HadoopShimsSecure.java:358)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat.getSplits(CombineHiveInputFormat.java:387)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:983)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeSplits(JobClient.java:975)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.access$500(JobClient.java:170)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:886)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:839)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1177)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:839)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:813)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:435)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExecDriver.main(ExecDriver.java:677)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:197)
```

Comment: set hive.exec.mode.local.auto=true..isn't it local mode?

Comment: @Tariq, yes, i did set this option - `set hive.exec.mode.local.auto=true`

Comment: Apologies, I misread it. Please make sure you have proper permissions.